How use datastore for save token
I don't know how to call or use dataStore other than in the viewmodel
I want to use the token value from the data store, to save the value it works, but when I call the datastore to the MainRemote.kt file a problem occurs, I only know how to use it in the viewmodel
this code in my MainRemote.kt
class MainRemote() {
    var authDataStorePreferences = ConnectionReleaseApplication().authDataStorePreferences
    init {

    }

    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        defaultRequest {
            url(host = BuildConfig.apiDomain, port = 3000)
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }

        install(Auth){
            bearer {
                loadTokens {
                    BearerTokens("token","mklklkl")
                }
            }
        }
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(
                Json {
                    prettyPrint = true
                    isLenient = true
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true

                }
            )
            install(Logging) {
                logger = Logger.ANDROID
                level = LogLevel.BODY
            }
        }


    }
}

this code when i register datastore in file ConnectionReleaseApp.kt
private const val AUTH_PREFERENCES_NAME = "auth_preferances_name"
private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = AUTH_PREFERENCES_NAME)

class ConnectionReleaseApplication : Application() {
    lateinit var authDataStorePreferences: AuthDataStorePreferences

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        authDataStorePreferences = AuthDataStorePreferences(dataStore)
    }
}

Error in my logcat
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property authDataStorePreferences has not been initialized
                                                                                                        at com.example.connectionmobile.ConnectionReleaseApplication.getAuthDataStorePreferences(ConnectionReleaseApplication.kt:14)
                                                                                                        at com.example.connectionmobile.api.remote.MainRemote.<init>(MainRemote.kt:22)
                                                                                                        at com.example.connectionmobile.api.repository.AuthRepository.login(AuthRepository.kt:12)
                                                                                                        at com.example.connectionmobile.viewModel.LoginViewModel.login(LoginViewModel.kt:55)
                                                                                                        at com.example.connectionmobile.ui.screen.LoginScreenKt$LoginScreen$1$4$1.invokeSuspend(LoginScreen.kt:77)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:68)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1542)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1553)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1109)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:984)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1527)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:257)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:368)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8826)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:572)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)

enter image description here

Please paste the error as text and remove the screenshot.

You should always the Hilt to manage the dependency injection in the Android app. To make your DataStore instance available to any component or class you can write a hilt module:
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object DataStoreModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthPreference(
        dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
    ): AuthDataStorePreferences = AuthDataStorePreferences(dataStore)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePreferenceDataStore(@ApplicationContext context: Context): DataStore<Preferences> {
        return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create {
            context.preferencesDataStoreFile("auth_preferances_name")
        }
    }
}

and then in your MainRemote class:
class MainRemote() {
    @Inject
    lateint var authDataStorePreferences: AuthDataStorePreferences
    
    //rest of the code 
}



Read more about hilt on official docs


You should never construct Application and Activity directly from the constructor like you did with ConnectionReleaseApplication() because they will be created by the Android system thus the onCreate() function won't be executed if you constructing them directly.
What you can do, pass the instance of the DataStore to your MainRemote constructor like this
class MainRemote(private val authDataStorePreferences: AuthDataStorePreferences) {
    // ...
}

Then in places where you create the MainRemote, pass the instance of the DataStore inside the constructor, assuming you would create it inside a composable function.
@Composable
fun Somewhere() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mainRemote = remember {
        val application = (context.applicationContext as ConnectionReleaseApplication)
        MainRemote(application.authDataStorePreferences)
    }
}

If you haven't added the ConnectionReleaseApplication in your AndroidManifest.xml then you should do it to make the system create it for you.
<application
    android:name=".ConnectionReleaseApplication"

    >

Note that even though the solution above would work, it's not a recommended practice. You should learn to use patterns like Dependency Injection and ViewModel instead.
